# How to use Wiremock to stub external URL?

Tags: wiremock, spring-cloud-contract

I want to stub an external request using Wiremock something like below:

```
WireMock.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("https://rest.api.com/status"))
      .withRequestBody(equalToJson("dummy-json"))
      .willReturn(responseDefinition()
      .withBody("json-body")
      .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)));
```

The stub is not getting called, and the code returns 401 unauthorized error.

I am using Spring Boot and have configured Wiremock as `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, httpsPort = 8080)`

Is there something I am missing in the configuration. I have tried using proxy and using WireMockRestServiceServer as described [Spring cloud documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.1.x/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_wiremock.html#_wiremock_and_spring_mvc_mocks).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `rest.api.com` you should call `localhost:8080`. This is where WireMock starts.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to test against an external API, is that not supported?

Comment: No. What you should do is make the host and port injectable as a property and then for the sake of tests you inject the wiremock's host and port